# Kill it with enchanted lava: [offtopic]

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Only three posts with [offtopic](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/offtopic) and [all are closed](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/offtopic). Can we bannish the tag for good never to be used again? How about its hyphenated Siamese [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/off-topic) that doesn't yet exist, but could?

Comment: The tag should soon disappear.

Comment: Enchanted lava?

Comment: @splattne Thanks! Can you add the proper tag now?

Comment: @WesleyDavid I'm sorry - I'd like to, but site moderators aren't allowed to add strings to the blacklisted user input table.

Comment: @splattne Tonight, ***we riot!***

Answer (score 1):

Looks like neither [offtopic](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/offtopic) nor [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/off-topic) exist. Excellent!

They are likely best managed by either manual retagging or simple removal of the questions that, by definition, are off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for poking this old question! I was meaning to go back through and see what remained of my crusades. =)